# How to use query filtering in ORDS on values in an array

Tags: json, oracle, api, oracle-ords

I have a ORDS GET API endpoint structured as follows available at a sample URI like this
https://myapi.test/data/customer/:customer_id/connections

```
select :customer_id as CUSTOMER_ID, CURSOR(SELECT CONNECTION_ID,IS_ACTIVE from CONNECTIONS where CONNECTION_CUSTOMER_ID = :customer_id) AS CONNECTIONS FROM DUAL
```

This works fine and produces a JSON in this format when used with a :customer_id = 12345

```
{
    "customer_id": "12345",
    "connections": [{
        "connection_id": "123",
        "is_active": 0
    }, {
        "connection_id": "456",
        "is_active": 0
    }, {
        "connection_id": "789",
        "is_active": 1
    }, {
        "connection_id": "10",
        "is_active": 1
    }]
}
```

Now I want to use the built-in ORDS query filtering options documented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-rest-data-services/23.1/orddg/developing-REST-applications.html#GUID-091748F8-3D14-402B-9310-25E6A9116B47:%7E:text=processed%20without%20errors-,2.3.2%20Filtering%20in%20Queries,-This%20section%20describes) to only show the connections that are active on my customer.

This is when I run into problems. These are the formatting options I have tried and the result.

| Format | Result | Error message |
| --- | --- | --- |
| {"connections[*].active:"1"} | 400 - bad request | no message |
| {"connections.active:"1"} | 400 - bad request | no message |
| {"connections":{"connection_id":"123"}} | 403 - forbidden | The request could not be processed because a function referenced by the SQL statement being evaluated is not accessible or does not exist |
| {"connections[*]":{"connection_id":"123"}} | 403 - forbidden | The request could not be processed because a function referenced by the SQL statement being evaluated is not accessible or does not exist |

At this point, I'm starting to wonder if it is possible to filter on the values inside an array. And if that is possible, then I'm guessing that my use of the CURSOR function to create the array is what is causing me grief.

Comment: Nothing is build into ORDS to allow this out-of-the-box as far as I know, but it may be possible to build it yourself.

Comment: Well that would be a really neat feature for some release in the future and allow the built-in query filtering to be even more useful @thatjeffsmith! For now I guess I'll have to use the query string to pass in some optional parameters and then buil my own filtering logic on those - as documented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-rest-data-services/23.1/orddg/developing-REST-applications.html#GUID-4A7F4425-61DF-4290-AED0-05DC2EF77158)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else looking at how to do this, currently i found no way to do this with the built-in filtering just like @thatjeffsmith said in his comment to my original question. The solution I used in the end was the query string to pass in a optional parameter, I then use that parameter in my sql to do the filtering. Thus my original query then became:

```
select :customer_id                                                as CUSTOMER_ID,
   CURSOR (SELECT CONNECTION_ID,
                  IS_ACTIVE
           from CONNECTIONS
           where CONNECTION_CUSTOMER_ID = :customer_id
             AND (:p_active is null or IS_ACTIVE = :p_active)) AS CONNECTIONS
FROM DUAL
```

This allows me to not apply the filter by not sending the optional parameter, or apply the filter by setting `?is_active=1` or `?is_active=0`.

Answer (score 0):

please try `https://myapi.test/data/customer/:customer_id/connections?q={"is_active":1}`. If this doesn't work, please provide actual API details.

Comment: I tried this and it did not work. The same request as the last two in my question - 403 and "The request could not be processed because a function referenced by the SQL statement being evaluated is not accessible or does not exist"

Comment: Please provide actual api details

Comment: The API is not publicly available, the information I have supplied should be sufficient to recreate the situation.